# java.io.IOException - 'Stream closed'

Tags: java

I am getting "java.io.IOException - 'Stream closed'" exception in following code:

```java
try (final ByteArrayOutputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    final InputStream inputStream = httpRequest.getInputStream();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, targetStream);
    }
    body = new String(targetStream.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    targetStream.flush();
}
```

Why is this happening and how to fix?

Comment: `targetStream.flush();` not required. It will be called impliciply by `close()` in `finally` block.

Comment: Probably `httpRequest.getInputStream()` was closed before `try` block.

Comment: I removed the flush(), still it didn't work.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @aby007, code looks well, probably `httpRequest.getInputStream()` was closed before `try` block. Check it.

Comment: IOUtils.copy(inputStream, targetStream);   This line throws the exception. but the inputStream is not closed before in the code. So it is confusing

Comment: TaskExecutionResource taskExecutionResource = objectMapperResource.readValue(httpRequest.getInputStream(), TaskExecutionResource.class);   
  Found this where the stream might be closed, what should be the solution for this?

Comment: objectMapperResource.disable(Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE);
seems objectMapper auto closes the stream, so I disabled it and now the problem is fixed.
Thank you for your help.